# Science of soap bubbles

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

On the web there are tons of different recipes for a solution to make soap bubbles.
Most of them use only three ingredients:

- water
- dish soap
- glycerin

But their ratios widely change among the sources.
Right now I'm using: 20:5:2 in volume.

The bubbles come out, but not as I desire.
Compared to a commercial solution, mine are bigger but last shorter. End if I constantly blow with some strength, the commercial solution produce literally *hundreds* of small bubbles (diameter between 1 and 4 cm), while mine will just make a couple of middle-sized bubbles and then the membrane will break.

The goal is to make a solution that allows to:

- make big bubbles if the blow is weak
- make a lot of small bubbles if the blow is strong
- maximize the duration of the bubbles

I will appreciate any hint in this direction, but I'm also interested to understand how to tune the ratios of the 3 ingredients. I mean, given the requirements above (I guess they are the most common!) how would you calculate the ratios?

Of course I can experiment. But I want to *learn* the theory behind.